# Change KDE Task Switcher thumbnail selected color

Tags: kde, colors, plasma

I'd like to change the color of the selected item in KDE task switcher, since I find it really hard to see. Though I have not been able to find out how to do it through system Settings.

Here is a pic of how it's now and somewhat how I'd like it to be.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**KDE Plasma**

The KDE task switcher is part of the plasma desktop so it is using the Plasma desktop theme elements.

The plasma theme elements are SVG pictures.

[image]

By the Plasma Theme Details: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/ThemeDetails the viewitem.svgz is

> viewitem.svgz: controls the background look of selections (results in
>   KRunner, networks in network applet), it can have 4 elements of 9
>   parts each with prefix normal, hover, selected, selected+hover.

[image]

Making and editing the KDE plasma themes: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/Theme

Comment: Ended up with a mix of themes, with the viewitem.svgz from Slim Glow http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Slim+Glow?content=74329

Comment: I want to make sure I understand this correctly. The only way to change the colors used by a Task Switcher app is to edit its SVG file, the colors are not configurable via any control panel applet?

Comment: Oh my god, it really is true. And somebody tried to [submit a patch](https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/108400/) which got _rejected_. A year ago. So the task-switcher for the default theme that comes with Kubuntu still has a barely visible highlight color. LOL. Fixed by ditching the Air theme.